# Save graphs from lists with mapply [R]

Tags: r, list, graph, mapply

I would like to save multiple graphs from the large list `df` (list containing lists).
with the following code I can generate the graph

```
require(oce)
mapply(function(dat, nm) { 
  plotProfile(dat, xtype="temperature",
col.temperature="black") 
  },
dat = df, nm = names(df))
```

But now I would like to extract the graphs in one pdf (if possible). With something like

```
pdf("~path/*.pdf")
#the code
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run and plot the function, you can just simply put it after the `pdf` call and it'll save them all in the pdf,

```
pdf("~path/*.pdf")
mapply(function(dat, nm) { 
    plotProfile(dat, xtype="temperature",
col.temperature="black") 
},
dat = df, nm = names(df))
dev.off()
```

Also, it'll be nice to have a reprex containing the dataframe to test it out.

Comment: Thank you it works. I don't know why it didn't worked previous time